# Unable to execute query on MS Access db on network

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, ms-access

I have ASP.Net website that imports data from MSAccess database on some shared network location into the SQL Server. People before have implemented the ASP.Net timer to update the progress bar on UI and Actual import process takes place on separate thread.

When I try the process by launching website from visual studio it works fine for files on both local and network location. But when I host the website on IIS, it works fine only for the database files located on local drive, if any database file shared on network drive the first select query on the database table just does not returns control, system just stops there and nothing happens. And UI progress keeps on showing the same message.

I have given the required permissions to the folder, for the User Account I have used on Application Pool.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can the user account under which the IIS application is executing access the network location?

Comment: Yes. The user read/write permissions on the folder. Now the website have stopped import data even from Visual Studio. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, actually that select query was to get the count of records it was doing count(*) instead of count of any column name. Table had many columns, so it was taking long. I just put the column name instead of * and it is working fine now.

But interesting thing to notice is the amount of time it takes.